# Genereate OpenAPI specification from typescript type

Tags: typescript, openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying to generate a typecsript type from a OpenAPI specification.

The generated typescript should be equal to

```
export type output = 'option1' | 'option2' | 'option3' | 'option4' | string;
```

currently my OpenApi specification is

```
schemas:
    output:
      type: object 
      additionalProperties:
        oneOf:
          - type: string
          - type: string
            enum: 
            - option1
            - option2
            - option3
            - option4
```

but this OpenAPI Specification does not generate the desired typeScript output.

Comment: Your `output` type is equivalent to `string`.

Comment: How do I acheive the output `export type output = 'option1' | 'option2' | 'option3' | 'option4' | string; ` like this ?

Comment: What? I'm saying your desired output type is equivalent to just `string`. The union is reduced to `string` since the other members are subsets of the type `string`.